# Is it appropriate to use MFCs PropertySheet for a TDI-application?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mfc

I think it is possible to write a [TDI-Application](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tabbed_document_interface) with MFCs [CPropertySheet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d3fkt014%28VS.80%29.aspx) class. Is this the right way to do it, or is there a standard way with not using this class?

It should also be possible to include a status-, menu- and toolbar into the application.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is a bad idea.

If you have VS2008 (with MFC Feature Pack) or above then when you make a new MFC MDI application, it will do all the hard work of creating a TDI interface for you.

See [here](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/cpp_mfc/tutorials/article.php/c14929) for a tutorial.

Comment: Thanks for your help, i was wondering why my question doesn't get any attention (except your answer). Was it the wrong time i wrote it or a bad title or is nobody using mfc any more, hmm no idea. Regarding your answer: I'm thinking about using VS2008 but there are some dependencies to libraries compiled with VC 6.0 (different time_t type 32/64 bit) and i don't like to struggle with that.

Comment: "Nobody using MFC any more" - I'd say that's fairly accurate nowadays, compared with 10yrs ago anyway. I can't see anything obviously wrong with your question, it's fine.